# WPF xaml binding ComboBox Background Color to SelectedItem's color

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, combobox, selecteditem

I have made a ComboBox class to enable commands, and I would like to send the ComboBox's Background color as a CommandParameter. I want to bind the ComboBox's Background to the SelectedItem's Background color.

For the ComboBox Style which binds and sends the CommandParameter I have

```
    <Style x:Key="colorComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type local:ColorComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource AnnotationToolbarComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="***SOME BINDING HERE???***"/>
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ChangeColor, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Background}"/>
        <Setter Property="CurrentColor" Value="{Binding CurrentColor, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Style>
```

And for the ComboBox with the ComboBoxItems. I would want to bind to the Background of these ComboBoxItems.

```
        <local:CommandableComboBox Background="Red">
            <ComboBoxItem Width="50" Height="50" Background="Blue"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Width="50" Height="50" Background="Green"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Width="50" Height="50" Background="Red"/>
        </local:CommandableComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding SelectedItem.Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```